# How do you debug html imports in webstorm?

Tags: html, debugging, polymer, webstorm

I am trying to debug code that is inside HTML imports in webstorm? I am working on a polymer project and am trying to debug the web component declared in:

```
  <link rel="import" href="core-collapse.html">
```

The breakpoints are hit fine in the loading page but no code is hit inside core-collapse.html.

Answer (score 0):

[WEB-10145](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10145) is fixed in WebStorm 9. Please try the [EAP build](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+9+EAP)